# '+=' cannot be applied to two [AnyObject] operands

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout

I have the following code to try and create an array of constraints to add to a view:

```
let views = ["button": button]
let metrics = ["margin": 16]

var constraints: [AnyObject] = []
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-margin-[button]-margin-|", options: 0, metrics: metrics, views: views)
```

From what I understand about Swift arrays, I should just be able to '+=' them together to join the two, but I get an error:

> "Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two [AnyObject] operands"

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Now a critical question - a lot changed in Xcode 7, released two days ago as of this comment.

Comment: Xcode 6.3.2 is what I'm on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not because of the operator.
It's because you are passing in an Int where you are actually supposed to pass `NSLayoutFormatOptions` enum type.

If you pass in one of the `NSLayoutFormatOptions` enum for the `options` parameter, the error will go away:

```
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-margin-[button]-margin-|", options: .AlignAllLeft, metrics: metrics, views: views)
```

Or you could also initialize the `NSLayoutFormatOptions` with the Int value that you want to use, like this:

```
NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)
```

0 would have worked in Objective-C, but you need to use the actual enum value in Swift.
The Swift errors are still often misleading in many cases, like this one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just came to this same conclusion. The Xcode compiler had me running in circles telling me the wrong error... 

Comment: Yeah.. hopefully Xcode will provide more useful error explanations soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try saving the results of constraintsWithVisualFormat into a temporary constant, then assigning it.

```
let newConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-margin-[button]-margin-|", options: 0, metrics: metrics, views: views)
constraints += newConstraints
```

Comment: Turns out it was the format options enum causing the error. Xcode just didn't do a very good job saying what the error was....

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

Xcode was listing the wrong thing as the error, which is what led to all this confusion. Using an Int of 0 for my format options apparently does not make the compiler happy, so instead I had to use `NSLayoutFormatOptions(0)`.

With that, the finished working code is like this:

```
var constraints: [AnyObject] = []
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-margin-[button]-margin-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `.AlignAllLeft` instead of `NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)` was not what caused the error. The array of constraints should have been statically-typed.

```
// BEFORE:
// var viewConstraints: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
// AFTER:  
var viewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
let views = NSDictionary(object: customView, forKey: "customView")

viewConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[customView]|",
    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
    metrics: nil,
    views: views as! [String : AnyObject])

// "Convert to Swift 2.0" Xcode option suggests syntax:
viewConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[customView]|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: views as! [String : AnyObject])
```

That appears good, because I want "no options" value.